# how to display a location using geocoder?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to display a location address in google map using Geocoder object .
for this i make a class FetchAddressIntentService extends IntentService and override onHandleIntent() method and using explicit intent starts this service.
but the problem is when i start service by using startService(intent) onHandleIntent() method is not call .

i follow the same code which is available on the android.developer site:

https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html

this is my code:

```
public class FetchAddressIntentService extends IntentService {
    protected ResultReceiver mReceiver;

    public FetchAddressIntentService() {

        super("abc");

    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onHandleIntent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String errorMessage="";

        Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

        Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA);



        List<Address> addresses=null;

        try {
            addresses=geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorMessage="unhendle IO exception";
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"unhendle IO exception",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if(addresses==null && addresses.size()==0){
            if(errorMessage.isEmpty()){
                errorMessage="no address found";
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"no address found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.FAILURE_RESULT, errorMessage);
        }
        else{

            Address address=addresses.get(0);
            ArrayList<String> arrayListFrag=new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i=0;i<address.getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++){

                arrayListFrag.add(address.getAddressLine(0));
            }

            deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.SUCCESS_RESULT,
                    TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"),
                            arrayListFrag));

        }
    }

    private void deliverResultToReceiver(int successResult, String message) {

        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY,message);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"resultData",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mReceiver.send(successResult,bundle);
    }
}
```

these method are use for start intent service:

```
 protected void startIntentService(){
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,FetchAddressIntentService.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.RECEIVER, mResultReceiver);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA, mLastLocation);
        startService(intent);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"startIntentService",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


   public void fetchAddressButtonHandler(){
        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mLastLocation!=null){
            startIntentService();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"fetchAddressButtonHandler",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


   }
```

manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.missionandroid.googlemapproject">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>

<service android:name=".FetchAddressIntentService"
    android:exported="false"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works fine for getting complete address from the current lat long:

Try this:

```
Geocoder geocoder; 
List<Address> addresses; 
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault()); 

addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(your current lat, your current long, 1);

String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); 
String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality(); 
String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea(); 
String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName(); 
String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode(); 
String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
```